# callbacks in MVC

Tags: php, model-view-controller

```
public function test(){
        $data = ORM::factory('testdata')->find_all();

        Table::factory()
            ->set_body_data($data)
            ->set_row_titles('id')
            ->set_column_titles(Table::AUTO)
            ->set_callback('format_row', 'row')
            ->render(true);

            $this->template->title = '';
            $this->template->payment_content = '';
    }

    function format_row($row, $index){
        if ($index % 2 == 0) return new Tr('', 'zebra');
    }
```

// getting an error : callback function format_row does not exist!, both methods declared in a controller class (Payment_Controller)

how do I do callbacks in MVC?

Comment: Could you describe the problem in greater detail – and be more exact with the error?

Comment: just added an additional comment...hope that helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `format_row()` also belongs to the class where the `test()` method is, then the callback should be passed as `array($this, 'format_row')`. So, perhaps you should change the line 7 of `test()` to `->set_callback(array($this, 'format_row'), 'row')`.

Comment: how would I do it if the callback is in another controller class, say in a class declares as Main_Controller

Comment: Then, `array(new Main_Controller, 'format_row')` if it's an instance method, or `array('Main_Controller', 'format_row')` if it's a static one.

Comment: thanks! I was looking to implement this in Kohana because my callbacks for checking if a field is already existing is defined in the controller thus forcing me to use $this when I could have called the class responsible for looking up entries! thanks a lot!